# Is there a way to build tests with bazel without running them?

Tags: bazel

Every time I run `bazel test <targets...>` it builds all target test binaries and runs them.  Is there a way to only compile them or build them without running them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bazel build <targets...>` to just build those targets without running the tests.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that test targets would be treated differently than regular targets.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to build test targets *only*, pass the `--build_tests_only` flag.